# Safari doesn't trigger jquery change when selecting a saved form value - alternatives?

Tags: jquery, safari

In Safari...
If you attach jquery .change() to a form element, it will be triggered if you type a value in the field and then navigate away from the field. However, if you begin typing and select a value from the list of previously entered values that Safari has saved, .change() is not triggered at all.

Other browsers work consistently -- regardless of whether you're typing the value or selecting from the saved list of values, it will trigger the onchange event.

Does anyone know of workarounds to trigger off a change in the form field in Safari when selecting from the saved value list?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the event to .blur() and it works fine. For my purposes, the events were interchangeable. Though if anyone knows of a more precise alternative to .change() in Safari with this use case, it would be helpful to know.